# Create View Controller with Parameters

Tags: objective-c

I would like to create a new viewController and pass data along when I instantiate.

I have a dictionary with some data and would like to access that data as soon as the viewController is created.

I've tried this:

```
//create the recipe
    myRecipe = [[RecipeCard alloc] init];
        //create a dictionary here...

//call the setRecipeItems method of the recipe I have created
        [myRecipe setRecipeItems: dictionary]

;
```

The problem is that the setRecipeItems fires before the view did load.

Ideally, I would like to do something like:

myRecipe = [[RecipeCard alloc] initWithData:dictionary];

But that hasn't worked for me

Thanks

Comment: After writing this, I figured I can just set the data with the first method, then use that data in a method I call after ViewDidLoad, but I'm curious if this is possible so I didn't delete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do exactly what you are asking by doing this:
(place this in your .h file)

```
@interface RecipeCard : UIViewController {
  NSDictionary *recipes;
}

- (id)initWithRecipes:(NSDictionary *)Recipes;

@end
```

(Then in your .m file)

```
@implementation RecipeCard

- (id)initWithRecipes:(NSDictionary *)Recipes
{
  if(self = [super init]) {
    recipes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:Recipes];
    [recipes retain];
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

Now you can create your RecipeCard like this:

```
myRecipe = [[RecipeCard alloc] initWithRecipes:someDictionaryObject];
```